Running sum using self join
I have been trying to understand the execution of this query which calculates the running sum using self join. I tried to visualize but what I think is it should actually start from bottom-up rather than top-bottom. Meaning the total of all salaries should come first and then it will decrease with number of IDs.
Am I wrong here ? or missing any concept ?
Table : emp_details



id
name
salary




1
Shripadh
10000


2
Satya
1400


3
Jia
500


4
David
1800


5
Michael
3000


6
Arvind
2400


7
Asha
4200


8
Maryam
3500


9
Reshma
2000


10
Akshay
2500



SELECT *,
  (
    SELECT SUM(T2.[SALARY])  
    FROM emp_details AS T2
    WHERE T2.[ID] <= T1.[ID]
  ) AS [Running Total]
FROM emp_details AS T1


Please tag your DBMS, you probably just want a window function SUM(T.SALARY) OVER (ORDER BY T.ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) without any joins.

what is your expected output?

Hard to understand, you should improve your question by adding the expected outcome. If I understand correct, you want this?: db<>fiddle

The running total calculation order cannot be specified because SQL is a declarative language.
It can be assumed that the calculation is performed incrementally as you move through the table in the order specified in the query, i.e. in the following example - from top to bottom.
This is more explicitly stated in the expression
sum(salary)over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)

Consider several queries for calculating running totals.
In fiddle we can see query plans.
create table emp_details(id int, name varchar(20), salary int);
insert into emp_details values
 (1,    'Shripadh', 10000)
,(2,    'Satya',    1400)
,(3,    'Jia',      500)
;
select * from emp_details;




id
name
salary




1
Shripadh
10000


2
Satya
1400


3
Jia
500



Your query
SELECT *,
  (
    SELECT SUM(T2.[SALARY])  
    FROM emp_details AS T2
    WHERE T2.[ID] <= T1.[ID]
  ) AS [Running Total]
FROM emp_details AS T1




id
name
salary
Running Total




1
Shripadh
10000
10000


2
Satya
1400
11400


3
Jia
500
11900




OR JOIN and Aggregate
SELECT t1.id ,max(t1.name) name,sum(t2.salary) as running_total
FROM emp_details t1
LEFT JOIN emp_details t2
    on t2.Id<=t1.Id
group by t1.id


OR
SELECT *
FROM emp_details AS T1
CROSS apply   (
    SELECT SUM(T2.[SALARY])  [Running Total]
    FROM emp_details AS T2
    WHERE T2.[ID] <= T1.[ID]
  ) AS totals



OR with windows function
select id,name
  ,sum(salary)over(order by id 
     rows between unbounded preceding and current row)Running_Total
from emp_details 

output is the same.

Thank you mate for the complete explanation. I was comparing the output in excel file with row by row calculation but was confused as to why the sql is not showing any output in the descending order..

If you need decreasing sum, just reverse the condition T2.[ID] <= T1.[ID] as T2.[ID] >= T1.[ID] So it sums all items after and including the current.
For example the first line with T1.ID=1 sums whole table by condition T2.ID >= 1 that is true for all rows.
